# Google Maps Location different results

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am developing google maps location API but the result from it is different from the reference website. Reference website has more results whereas mine one has less results.

Following is code I am using for google autocomplete:

```
var placeSearch, autocomplete;

    var componentForm = {
      street_number: 'short_name',
      route: 'long_name',
      locality: 'long_name',
      administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
      country: 'long_name',
      postal_code: 'short_name'
    };

    var options = {
        types: ['geocode','establishment']
    };

    function initAutocomplete() {
      // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search predictions to
      // geographical location types.
      autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
          document.getElementById('autocomplete'), options);

      // Avoid paying for data that you don't need by restricting the set of
      // place fields that are returned to just the address components.
      autocomplete.setFields(['address_component']);

      // When the user selects an address from the drop-down, populate the
      // address fields in the form.
      autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
    }

    function fillInAddress() {
        filledFlag = false;
      // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

      for (var component in componentForm) {
        console.log(component);
        document.getElementById(component).value = '';
        //document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
      }

      // Get each component of the address from the place details,
      // and then fill-in the corresponding field on the form.
      for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
        console.log(addressType);
        console.log(place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]]);
        if (componentForm[addressType]) {
          var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
          document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
        }
      }
      filledFlag = true;
    }

    // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
    // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
    function geolocate() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          var geolocation = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
          };
          var circle = new google.maps.Circle(
              {center: geolocation, radius: position.coords.accuracy});
          autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
        });
      }
    }
```

I am not sure about the code used in the reference website but I have attached some screenshots for reference.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: welcome to SO, take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before you start. Happy coding.

Comment: How is your code different from the "reference" website?  What reference website are you referring to?

Comment: @geocodezip No, I am don't have the code from the "reference" website. Reference website is https://www.cvent.com/venues/ anyways.